# C++ container with external references to its objects

Tags: c++, stl, containers, directx-11

(In the question below I use the term 'references' in general (it can be anything), and am not referring to the C++ concept of a reference.)

For DirectX 11 objects, I need a container / collection that is looped very often, and speed is key. I wanted to use a std::vector<>. But other objects would have a pointer to these objects, and whenever you add an object to a std::vector, the memory is reallocated and the pointers to it are invalid. So that does not work.

What would be a way to have a container that is looped fast, but also allows having references to its objects, without breaking those references when the container contents is changed?
The references must also be fast (directly point to the object), a look-up system is not desirable.

Are there 'standard ways' of using containers like this in graphical applications? I would think that this is a common design issue.

Thank you.

Comment: `std::deque` doesn't invalidate pointers or references when elements are appended or removed at either end.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will test how fast it is.